# Replace usage of WebServerFactoryCustomizer with TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webserver, javabeans

tl:dr; I want to be able to have square brackets in URL parameters `http://localhost:8080/controller/square?parameter=PL&parameter[wow]=wow` and following three Java files are doing that correctly. My question is how I can rewrite my code to be using https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.html?

Following three Java files are working correctly, they allow me to have `[]` character in the URL. But I would like to rewrite the code to use `TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer` but I do not know how and from where I should get values for its constructor: `TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer(Environment environment, ServerProperties serverProperties)` .

**Controller.java, file 1 of 3**

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "controller", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Controller {

  @GetMapping("/square")
  public ResponseEntity<String> requiredFields(
    @RequestParam(name = "parameter") final String parameter) {

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("OK");
  }
}
```

**CustomWebServerAllowingSquareWebBrackets.java, file 2 of 3**

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;

class CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters implements
  WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
      connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "[]");
    });
  }
}
```

**DemoForParametersWithSquareBracketsApplication.java, file 3 of 3**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoForParametersWithSquareBracketsApplication {

  /**
   * Bean for {@link WebServerFactoryCustomizer}.
   * @return static class with customised web server.
   */
  @Bean
  public CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters containerCustomizer() {
    return new CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoForParametersWithSquareBracketsApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

These three Java files above, after running allow you to execute successfully following GET request `http://localhost:8080/controller/square?parameter=PL&parameter[wow]=wow`.

Below you will find my modified classes, currently not working, of custom web server class, using *TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer*.

**Modified CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters.java, file 2 of 3**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConfigurableTomcatWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

class CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters extends TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer {

  public CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters(Environment environment, ServerProperties serverProperties) {
    super(environment, serverProperties);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableTomcatWebServerFactory factory) {
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
      connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "[]");
    });

    super.customize(factory);
  }
}
```

**Modified DemoForParametersWithSquareBracketsApplication.java, file 3 of 3**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoForParametersWithSquareBracketsApplication {

  /**
   * Bean for {@link WebServerFactoryCustomizer}.
   * @return static class with customised web server.
   */
  @Bean
  public CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters containerCustomizer() {
    // TODO it will NOT compile
    return new CustomWebServerAllowingSquareBracketsInParameters(null, null);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoForParametersWithSquareBracketsApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

My question is, from where and how I could get values `Environment environment, ServerProperties serverProperties` for the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Access Environment by `@Autowired` tag.

```java
    @Autowired
    protected Environment env;
```